# C++ typedef to variadic template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, variadic

I want to typedef a variadic template parameter like the attached code shows. It is possible to achive that?

```
template <typename... T>
class Test
{
public:
    typedef T Arg;
};

template <typename T>
class X
{
public:
    X(T::Arg arg);
};
```

Comment: Packs aren't types. They're weird things.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign a pack to a non-pack. You can put it into a `std::tuple` though.

```
template <typename... T>
class Test
{
public:
    typedef std::tuple< T ... > Arg;
};
```

Subsequently obtaining from `Arg` a function with parameter list `T ...` takes a bit more work, and I don't recommend doing so as a design pattern. It is probably better to couple `class Test` and `X::X` some other way.

Comment: Tha code I attached is just a test. I'm writing an extension layer which I can use this way: _class myclass : public extensible<myclass_extension_descriptor>_. And the myclass_extension_descriptor is a _typedef to descriptor<myclassInterface, /* myclassInterface's constructor parameters */>_. And the extensible class has a load_extension method which would look like this: _void load_extension(const std::string& path, myclass_extension_descriptor::Args... args)_.